# Дамп std::vector в файл

Tags: c++, vector

Я хочу сохранить все значения массива в файл. Сам вектор представляет из себя `std::vector<some_struct> users`. Я пытался сделать вот так

```
std::fstream savef;
savef.open(filename,std::ios_base::binary|std::ios_base::out|std::ios_base::trunc);
savef.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(users),sizeof(users));
savef.close();
```

Но получил ошибку `invalid cast`

Answer (score -1):

С c++11 у std::vector можно получить указатель на массив, который используется внутри

```
std::fstream savef;
savef.open(filename,std::ios_base::binary|std::ios_base::out|std::ios_base::trunc);
savef.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(users.data()), sizeof(value_type)*users.size());
savef.close();
```

[std::vector data()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/)

Comment: Дело в том то что размер каждого юзера в `users` разный, так как в структуре используются std::string в количестве двух штук.

Comment: На самом деле одинаковый, просто в структурах хранятся указатели на память, где эти строки хранятся. В общем у вас тут явно другая проблема

Comment: А если `some_struct` не POD, то получится простой перенос проблемы на более мелкий уровень. А раз автор пишет, что там есть `string` - то так и есть.